# Application crashes on start - how to get a crash dump file?

Tags: windows, crash-dumps, adplus

My winform application crashes as soon as its been launched. This problem is only happening in one of the client computer. Works fine for all other clients. I was thinking of using ADPlus to get a crash dump but problem is in order to configure ADPlus in crash mode, debugger need to be attached to running application first. That means application must be running when I configure ADPlus, however, as I said my application crashes as soon as I start it. It does not give me a chance to run ADPlus. Any idea if ADPlus can be used in this scenario? Are there any other tools that I can use generate a process dump in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't start the program and then attach a debugger in time, you can try one of the following ideas:

- Start the program *under the debugger* on the machine where it's crashing. [As already mentioned,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866064/application-crashes-on-start-how-to-get-a-crash-dump-file/8905331#8905331) ProcDump is enough for that purpose, or you can use Visual Studio or WinDBG.
- If you can't easily start the program under the debugger (for example, if it is actually a Windows service), [use `gflags` to make Windows start the program under the debugger.](http://bugslasher.net/2010/10/14/how-to-debug-a-windows-service/) This will create a subkey for your program filename [under the `Image File Execution Options` registry key.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/a329t4ed(v=vs.100))
- [Set your debugger as the postmortem debugger, so it always launches when any program crashes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff542967)

If and when the crash happens, the debugger will automatically break in and either create a dump automatically or let you create one manually.

If you can't run a debugger, not even ProcDump, you can use Windows' built-in crash dump facility to create a dump automatically:

- On Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, set Dr. Watson as the postmortem debugger by running this command:

  ```
  drwtsn32 -i
  ```

  Here is info on what this command does and how to use Dr. Watson: [Capturing Application Crash Dumps](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/15/capturing-application-crash-dumps.aspx)
- On Windows Vista SP1, Windows Server 2008, and later, set Windows Error Reporting to save dumps locally by creating this registry key:

  ```
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
  ```

  You don't need to create or set any values or subkeys under this key. If you want to change settings, here is more info: [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb787181)

  Note that "applications that do their own custom crash reporting, including .NET applications, are not supported by" WER. This is a problem for you because your app uses WinForms - although there is some indication that the feature does work with .NET 4 apps on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) from Sysinternals to capture a dump.